# DC/DC output ripple voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ldo, texas-instruments

Our team is using TI's TPS62740 IC as a DC-DC converter in our device. At Vout (without connecting load) I get a sawtooth waveform of about 9 mV peak to peak.

[image]

After adding a 2nd order low pass filter (2.2 uH and 10 uF) to it,the ripple dropped to 2.7-3 mV but the effect is not changed.

[image]

[image]

What are other techniques to reduce it?

We are operating at these conditions

- Vin = 3.6 V
- Vout = 2.5 V
- Iout = 50 mA

Our product is battery operated.  It is a current constrained device.

How can I get a clean DC output from this regulator?

Comment: hey I added  the schematic and waveforms of it respectively

Comment: Thanks! Try simulating moving some of C1-3 to before L1. Increasing L4 and decreasing the ESR of C28 will help too. What ESR do you have?

Comment: @vinayakpotadar:  What is the frequency of the sawtooth?  I can't make out the time per division on your oscilloscope.

Comment: The output ripple is inversely proportional to C28 and the switching frequency. Increase one or both.

Comment: Switching converters have those ripples by their nature (The waveform may change). You cannot completely get rid of them, but you can decrease them to an **acceptable level**. `the ripple dropped to 2.7-3 mV but the effect is not changed.` This level of ripple (nearly one-thousandth of the average voltage) a problem for your application?

Comment: yes, it affects my calculation. because if I use liner External power source and give it to my board then my Board works fine without any problem.

Comment: Affects calculation or cause problems?

Comment: It affects my MCU calculation.

Comment: What are those waveforms on the scope image? They can't be input and output from the filter because it looks like some form of time travel is happening. Is your scope timebase set too long and producing aliasing?

Comment: How? Are you using it as reference?

Comment: Your probing needs to be improved. The shape of the second trace indicates you are probably getting some effect due to ground impedance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After adding a 2nd order low pass filter (2.2 uH and 10 uF) to it,the ripple dropped to 2.7-3 mV but the effect is not changed.

Why do you think that the filter has no effect? I can clearly see on the oscilloscope the output ripple after the filter is lower. In fact, you said so yourself!

If you want to reduce the ripple even further, consider using a linear regulator output stage. Linear regulators have a much lower output noise compared to a DC-DC converter. It is not uncommon to cascade a DC-DC converter and a linear regulator.

But for your low power low noise application with a small difference between the input and output voltage, a pure linear regulator should do the job.

[image]